# Dragable and Clickable Push pin AJAX Bing Maps

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm trying to create a dragable push pin. However when I do this all other events, mousedown, click, dblclick, etc. all don't come through any more.

How would I go about creating a push pin that is both draggable and able to receive click events?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.garzilla.net/vemaps/Draggable-Push-Pins-with-Bing-Maps-7.aspx